# Convert c# date to Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, highcharts

This is how I convert .Net Datetime to Javascript. I found the code somewhere a long time ago and use it for Highcharts. Now the chart sometimes looks strange with the lines messed up. I suspect it has to do with the date.

```
Datetime curDate = "11/14/2013";
string jsDate = "Date.UTC(" + curDate.Year + "," + (curDate.Month - 1) + "," +     curDate.Day;
if (curDate.Millisecond > 0)
        {
            jsDate += "," + curDate.Hour + "," + curDate.Minute + "," + curDate.Second + "," + curDate.Millisecond;
            return jsDate += ")";
        }
        if (curDate.Second > 0)
        {
            jsDate += "," + curDate.Hour + "," + curDate.Minute + "," + curDate.Second;
            return jsDate += ")";
        }
        if (curDate.Minute > 0)
        {
            jsDate += "," + curDate.Hour + "," + curDate.Minute;
            return jsDate += ")";
        }
        if (curDate.Hour > 0)
        {
            jsDate += "," + curDate.Hour;
            return jsDate += ")";
        }

        jsDate += ")";
```

Is this a correct way to convert .Net date to javascript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to convert between the two is to convert the .NET time to a timespan in milliseconds from the UNIX epoch time:

```
public static long ToEpochDate(this DateTime dt)
{
    var epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    return dt.Subtract(epoch).Ticks;
}
```

You can then use that to generate your JS string:

```
DateTime current = DateTime.Now;
var jsDate = string.Format("Date.UTC({0})", current.ToEpochDate());
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew I got so much code for such a simple thing but it has worked (until now when occasionally, the lines are messed up) so I  was hesitated to change. But doing it my way, I believe does not convert the days (when a month has 31 days but converting back to the previous month that does not have the "31"). Anyway, thank you!

Comment: It converts to JS dates but did not work with HighCharts but that's not the question. My question is how to convert a .Net date to JavaScript.

Comment: @LacHo - Keep in mind, that if the only JS you're generating is in the call to `string.Format` you still need to wrap it in a call to new - `new Date(Date.UTC({0}));`